# In Java, what do the periods in this File location denote?

Tags: java, file-io, directory, directory-structure

I'm looking at some sample code for creating a File in Java:

```
File f = new File("test/.././file.txt");
```

I'm confused at how this works - how can you have "test" , and then those `..` and `.` in between like that? If I run this code in an arbitrary directory in my machine, why does it work(i.e I don't have a folder called "test" ).

this is part of some code for Path-Testing in java(getAbsolutePath() and etc)

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "why does it work"? What do you _do_ with the `File`? A `File` in Java is simply a path, it is not a file handle. The dots are standard URI syntax.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - ah I see what you mean. So when we compile this, it doesn't actually verify that the whole path exists. Ok I get it now. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `..` denote a parent directory; `.` denote this directory.

Having this as valid is another good reason why you should use `getCanonicalPath()` vs `getAbsolutePath()`

For example:
Lets say your file is under /folder1/folder2 directory

then

```
File f = new File("/folder1/folder2/folder3/../<your file>");
f.getCanonicalPath() ==> /folder1/folder2/<your file>
f.getAbsolutePath() ==> /folder1/folder2/folder3/../<your file>
```

Answer (score 2):

The .. just means "up a directory level". The single . just means "current directory level". Why they are in your file path is beyond me. Your path seems to mean "go into the test folder, then go up a level (to the one you started in), stay in that level, then look for file.txt". You could do the same thing with just new File("file.txt").

Answer (score 2):

```
File f = new File("test/.././file.txt");  //.. is used to go one hierarchy above in the directory structure and . is for current directory
```

suppose you have directory structure like ABC/test/file.txt
and if you are inside test then your . is path upto test
and .. is path upto ABC as .. represents parent directory and parent of "test" is "ABC"

Answer (score 1):

Because the `..`  goes back up the directory hierarchy, so you'll be back to where you started (not in test). This is  unnecessary as it's equivalent to:

`File("test.txt")`

And so should work regardless of which directory you run it in.

Comment: You are not always where you started: *"consider the path `a/../b`, which simplifyPath will change to `b`. If `a` is a symlink to `x`, `a/../b` may refer to a sibling of `x`, rather than the sibling of `a` referred to by `b`."* from [Guava/Files.simplifyPath](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#simplifyPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

The ".." will go up one directory from the current directory.  So, this code is basically the same as `new File("./file.txt");`

Answer (score 1):

./ goes to the directory where your project is located
../ Goes back a folder lets say you have a resource directory

Res/graphics/sprites/image.png

If you do File file = new File("./graphics/sprites/);
That will point to the sprites directory

Now if you want to go back a file dir File newFile = file + "../";